# Dropdown not opening when using focus and focusout

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-events

I have two dropdowns with same the same class let’s call it dropdown and I do this fiddle with the dropdowns with jQuery:

```
$('.dropdown').focus(function () {
    //Fiddle with this dropdown
}).focusout(function () {
    //Fiddle with this dropdown
});
```

When I jump between two dropdowns with the same class (dropdown) the drop down doesn’t open immediately instead it get focus and I have to click on it again in order to open it up. It seem to have something to do with the fact that I enable and disable options in the list when I fiddle with it. Is there a workaround?

(I have tried to use `blur` instead of `focusout` and the same problem occur)

**Edit:**

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TpYvz/3/)

JS:

```
$('.dropdown').focus(function () {
    var selectListIndex = $(this).attr('selectedIndex');
    $('.dropdown').each(function() {
        $('option:nth-child(' + (selectListIndex + 1) + ')', $(this)).attr('disabled', '');
    });
}).focusout(function () {
    var selectListIndex = $(this).attr('selectedIndex');
    $('.dropdown').not($(this)).each(function() {
        $('option:nth-child(' + (selectListIndex + 1) + ')', $(this)).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<select class="dropdown">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
</select>
<select class="dropdown">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I edited the question with a jsfiddle. This seem be an IE specific problem.

Comment: At least IE9 specific. hmm...

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$('.dropdown').focus(function () {
    $('.dropdown').focusout() 
});
```